# Magento and Paypal different amounts charged

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.9, paypal-adaptive-payments

wondering if anyone can help.

Im having a problem with our magento - paypal integration.

When a visitor on the website uses a discount code. The amount paypal collects is usually a different amount than shows in the magento order. This then flags up a fraudulent/suspicious transaction from magento as the total amounts are different.

For example
Item ordered on website is £135.00 inc VAT (20%) 
Discount code used (10% off) saving £13.50
Total amount to be paid is £121.50

So paypal should be collecting £121.50.

However this is what paypal are being told to collect.

```
amt=119.25 <<<- this is the amount PayPal captured for the total sale (should include shipping and taxes if known).
itemamt=112.50
shippingamt=0.00
taxamt=20.25
shipdiscamt= -13.50
`
So it looks like the cart calculated the following way: ItemAmt 112.50 + TaxAmt 20.25 = 132.75 - 13.50 discount = 119.25. .
```

Anyone got any ideas why this is happening and how I can correct this issue.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have the PayPal transaction ID?

Comment: Hello yes the Transaction ID is : "779803915S4346840".